# Why different reference is created for int object when passed to function in python?

Tags: python, list, reference

As per my knowledge the Python interpreter creates references from 0 to 256 for int objects, at the start itself. Here I got output `3`,`[44,2,3]`, for the list I understood, but why did the same thing not happen with the int object? I expected the output to be `1`,`[44,2,3]`. Can anyone please explain this behavior to me? I use Python 3.

```
def change(var, lst):
    var = 1
    lst[0] = 44
k = 3
a = [1, 2, 3]
change(k, a)
print(k)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
3
[44,2,3]
```

Expected output:

```
1
[44,2,3]
```

Comment: You reassign `var` to a different value. I'm not sure what you think that has to do with the implementation detail that Python caches references for certain ints.

Comment: You're doing two fundamentally different operations. If you did `lst = [44, 2, 3]`, i.e. assigning a new list to the local name in the same way you're assigning a new int `1` to the local name `var`, you'd see the same behaviour.